# IntelliJ 14 not able to run scala test

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

Recently, my newly created IntelliJ project failed to run scala test with following error in console:

> 2015-07-30 09:46:56,731 [72575363]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -
>   org/jetbrains/idea/maven/project/MavenProjectsManager 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jetbrains/idea/maven/project/MavenProjectsManager
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.AbstractTestRunConfiguration.provideDefaultWorkingDir(AbstractTestRunConfiguration.scala:122)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.AbstractTestRunConfiguration.initWorkingDir(AbstractTestRunConfiguration.scala:116)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.scalatest.ScalaTestConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationByLocation(ScalaTestConfigurationProducer.scala:62)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.AbstractTestConfigurationProducer$class.createConfigurationByElement(AbstractTestConfigurationProducer.scala:30)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.TestConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationByElement(TestConfigurationProducer.scala:18)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.TestConfigurationProducer.setupConfigurationFromContext(TestConfigurationProducer.scala:33)
>           at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.TestConfigurationProducer.setupConfigurationFromContext(TestConfigurationProducer.scala:18)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.createConfigurationFromContext(RunConfigurationProducer.java:87)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationProducer.findOrCreateConfigurationFromContext(RunConfigurationProducer.java:170)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.getConfigurationsFromContext(PreferredProducerFind.java:106)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.findConfigurationFromContext(PreferredProducerFind.java:131)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.PreferredProducerFind.createConfiguration(PreferredProducerFind.java:43)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.ConfigurationContext.createConfiguration(ConfigurationContext.java:119)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.ConfigurationContext.getConfiguration(ConfigurationContext.java:112)
>           at com.intellij.execution.actions.BaseRunConfigurationAction.update(BaseRunConfigurationAction.java:194)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction.beforeActionPerformedUpdate(AnAction.java:243)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:111)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:620)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.d(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:483)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:213)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   2015-07-30 09:46:56,731 [72575363]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4  Build
>   IU-141.1532.4  2015-07-30 09:46:56,731 [72575363]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_31  2015-07-30
>   09:46:56,731 [72575363]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM:
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM  2015-07-30 09:46:56,731 [72575363] 
>   ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
>   2015-07-30 09:46:56,731 [72575363]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux

I searched around, but couldn't find anything useful. Anyone had the same issue, and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Install the "Maven Integration" plugin from the settings.

If you're wondering how I solved that, I saw that there was a strange error even if you try to create a new spec2 configuration.

This was the error in my console:

```
[  73962]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -  org/jetbrains/idea/maven/project/MavenProjectsManager 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/idea/maven/project/MavenProjectsManager
at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.test.AbstractTestRunConfiguration.provideDefaultWorkingDir(AbstractTestRunConfiguration.scala:122)
```

The `org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager` class is in the maven plugin.

Installing solved that problem and this one.